# Javascript onclick isn't working, and I'm not getting anything

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I am trying to change the select query `onclick` of the button.

The table name, and field names in the table are equal to the fragment after page = (About, ContactInformation)

I'm not getting any error nor getting any result.

Index page code:

```
function selectQuery(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","queries.php?page="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}

<ul>
  <li><a href="?page=About" value="About" onclick="selectQuery(this.value)">
    <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;About us</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="?page=ContactInformation" onchange="selectQuery()">
    <i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

queries.php page (I can't seem to get the value of $page):

```
<?php
    $page = intval($_GET['page']);    
    echo $page;    
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you're missing return false; after the selectQuery() in onclick etc? not sure

Comment: Why is $page an integer? shouldn't it be a string?

Comment: why onchange over an anchor? and onchange="selectQuery()" no parameter as put..? and in the first anchor you use this.value, but anchor dont have value

Comment: I'm talking about the on click forget about the on change this is not even set later..

Comment: @MightyPork is right, you need something like `onclick="selectQuery(this.value); return false;"` to avoid reloading your page which causes you to not see the results.

Comment: @jeroen not reloading the page makes sense, cause it's an ajax request, but when i put return false, the page url stays index.php and not index.php?page=About which makes it impossible to process the request `xmlhttp.open("GET","queries.php?page="+str,true);` which also makes it impossible to get the value of the GET in the queries.php file so ?

Comment: You can use javascript to read and parse the value of for example the `href` attribute of the clicked link and use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```js
function selectQuery(obj) {
        var value = obj.getAttribute('data-value');
        
        if (value == "") {
            document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","queries.php?page="+value,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="?page=About" data-value="About" onclick="return selectQuery(this);"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;About us</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="editor"></div>
```

do not use value on a. set a data-attribute or use the value directly in the onclick function

Answer (score 0):

It works. Add **return false** and replace href with #
index.php

```
<script>
function selectQuery(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","queries.php?page="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#"  onclick="selectQuery('3'); return false;"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="?page=ContactInformation" onchange="selectQuery()"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact us</a></li>
</ul>
<p id="editor"></p>
```

queries.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    echo $_GET['page'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use `value for anchor tag` because it is `not defined` for anchor tag,you have to pass `string inside it` or `construct the string dynamically on click of your anchor tag`.currently for you `this.value` will give `undefined`,and use return false,and # in href.

try like this:

```
<script>
function selectQuery(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","submit.php?page="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="selectQuery('About');return false;"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;About us</a></li>
  <li><a href="?page=ContactInformation" onchange="selectQuery(this.value)"><i class="fa fa-list-alt"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Contact us</a></li>
</ul>

<p id="editor"></p>
```